# Ondraw method not calling in custom view

Tags: android, view, custom-view, viewgroup

I am making custom view using custom ViewGroup and custom View in Android.

```
public class Custom_ViewGroup extends ViewGroup
{
public Custom_ViewGroup(Context context)
{
    super(context);
    addView(new OwnView(context));
}

public Custom_ViewGroup(Context context,AttributeSet attrs) 
{
    super(context, attrs);
    addView(new OwnView(context));
}
@Override
protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b)
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

class OwnView extends View
{
    public OwnView(Context context)
    {
        super(context);
        System.out.println("on constructor");
    }
    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
    {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        System.out.println("ondraw child");
    }
  }
}
```

onDraw() method of OwnView class is not calling. constructor of OwnView class called. I have used invalidate() method after adding view, but it did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your problem

```
@Override
protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b)
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}
```

Your view is never laid-out, so it will not draw.  You need to implement the `onLayout` method properly.  Also, if your `ViewGroup` contains only a single view, consider using `FrameLayout` instead of `ViewGroup`.

Comment: "Also, if your `ViewGroup` is only a single view" you mean if it has only one child View?

Comment: so if it has only one child view, its better just to remove the "one child" parent

Comment: @pskink Possibly.  It depends on how the child view is laid-out.

Comment: @pathfinderelite thanks, It is working. But I did not understand your point to use FrameLayout. Can you put some more light on use of FrameLayout....

Comment: @Akashsingla19 I'm not saying you should use `FrameLayout`.  I'm saying you _may_ want to use it if your ViewGroup only contains a single child.  You can read more [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/FrameLayout.html)

Comment: @pathfinderelite ok. I made a demo to learn custom view and custom viewgroup. If you have any type of material on custom view, Please give me.

Comment: @Akashsingla19  Google is your friend :)